# How can I put the rectangle div on the space that was flex?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want the div rectangle will also columned on that space provided. I used display flex on the .education so that the other div will be at the side of the education however if I attach the other rectangle div on the bottom side of the 2 rectangle it is on the side instead. Please excuse my English.

How can I do that? Please help me thank you in advance!

```css
.resume-body {
  background-color: #1f2021;
}

.wrapper-body-resume {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

/* Header */
.header-resume {
  font-family: Arial;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 350px;
  z-index: 1;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgb(46, 46, 46), rgb(0, 0, 0));
}
.GP {
  background: url(../Resources/Aljon-GP.png);
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  bottom: 150px;
  left: 400px;
  position: relative;
}

.name-left {
  text-align: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 80px 0 0 0;
  margin: 0;
  left: 300px;
  position: relative;
}
.name-left h1 {
  line-height: 0;

  font-size: 30px;
  color: #ffffff;
}
.name-left p {
  color: #999999;
}
.body-resume {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

.about {
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 10px;
  font-family: Arial;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}
.about h1 {
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 5px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: Arial;
  color: #1f2021;
}
.about p {
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 5px;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-style: italic;
}

.personalinfo {
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 10px;
  font-family: Arial;
  width: 22%;
  height: 500px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}
.personalinfo h1 {
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 5;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: Arial;
  color: #1f2021;
}
.personalinfo p {
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 5px;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-style: italic;
}
.column1 {
  display: flex;
  flex: row;
}
.education {
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 10px;
  width: 30%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.education h1 {
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 5;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: Arial;
  color: #1f2021;
}

.education p {
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 5px;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-style: italic;
}
.workexper {
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 10px;
  font-family: Arial;
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}
.cert {
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 10px;
  font-family: Arial;
  width: 50%;
  height: 500px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}
```

```html
<main> 
<div class="wrapper-body-resume">

<div class="header-resume">
<div class="GP"></div>
<div class="name-left">
<h1>Aljo</h1>
<p style=" color: white"><i><b>logy</b></i></p>
<p style=" color: white">Contac +39</p>
<hr>
<p><i>"Th</i></p>
<p><i>-Colin Powell</i></p>
</div>
</div>

<div class="body-resume">
<div class="about">
    <h1>About me</h1>
    <p>I .</p>
</div>
<div class="column1">
<div class="education">
    <h1>Education</h1>
    <p><b><u>Elementary</u></b></p>
    <p><i><b>Sool</b></i><br>An9)</p>
    <p><i><b>Scia</b></i><br>P11)</p>

    <p><b><u>High School</u></b></p>
    <p><i><b>Hemy</b></i><br>An 2012)</p>
    <p><i><b>Frol</b></i><br>Po4)</p>
    <p><i><b>Ju</b></i><br>C 2015)</p>

    <p><b><u>College</u></b></p>
    <p><i><b>Uninan</b></i><br>C5 - 2019)</p>

</div>
<div class="personalinfo">
    <h1>Personal Info</h1>
    <p>
</div>
<div class="workexper">
</div>


</div>
<div class="cert">
</div>
</div>

</div>
</main>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You will need to put those two divs in another div. So the div containing work experience and personal info will will be displayed as blocks relative to the flex div they are inside of. I have attached the example code with the fix.

```css
.resume-body {
      background-color: #1f2021;
    }

    .wrapper-body-resume {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
    }

    /* Header */
    .header-resume {
      font-family: Arial;
      box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      margin: 0;
      position: relative;
      width: 100%;
      height: 350px;
      z-index: 1;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: row-reverse;
      background: linear-gradient(to right, rgb(46, 46, 46), rgb(0, 0, 0));
    }
    .GP {
      background: url(../Resources/Aljon-GP.png);
      width: 100%;
      height: 500px;
      background-size: contain;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      bottom: 150px;
      left: 400px;
      position: relative;
    }

    .name-left {
      text-align: center;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      justify-content: center;
      width: 50%;
      height: 100%;
      padding: 80px 0 0 0;
      margin: 0;
      left: 300px;
      position: relative;
    }
    .name-left h1 {
      line-height: 0;

      font-size: 30px;
      color: #ffffff;
    }
    .name-left p {
      color: #999999;
    }
    .body-resume {
      width: 100%;
      padding: 10px 20px;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    }

    .about {
      padding: 5px;
      margin: 10px;
      font-family: Arial;
      box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
    }
    .about h1 {
      padding: 10px;
      margin: 5px;
      font-size: 20px;
      font-family: Arial;
      color: #1f2021;
    }
    .about p {
      padding: 10px;
      margin: 5px;
      font-size: 16px;
      font-family: Arial;
      font-style: italic;
    }

    .personalinfo {
      padding: 5px;
      margin: 10px;
      font-family: Arial;
      width: 150px;
      height: 500px;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
    }
    .personalinfo h1 {
      padding: 10px;
      margin: 5;
      font-size: 20px;
      font-family: Arial;
      color: #1f2021;
    }
    .personalinfo p {
      padding: 10px;
      margin: 5px;
      font-size: 16px;
      font-family: Arial;
      font-style: italic;
    }
    .column1 {
      display: flex;
      flex: row;
    }
    .education {
      padding: 5px;
      margin: 10px;
      width: 30%;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
    }
    .education h1 {
      padding: 10px;
      margin: 5;
      font-size: 20px;
      font-family: Arial;
      color: #1f2021;
    }

    .education p {
      padding: 10px;
      margin: 5px;
      font-size: 16px;
      font-family: Arial;
      font-style: italic;
    }
    .workexper {
      padding: 5px;
      margin: 10px;
      font-family: Arial;
      width: 150px;
      height: 500px;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
    }
    .cert {
      padding: 5px;
      margin: 10px;
      font-family: Arial;
      width: 50%;
      height: 500px;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
    }
```

```html
<main> 
    <div class="wrapper-body-resume">

    <div class="header-resume">
    <div class="GP"></div>
    <div class="name-left">
    <h1>Aljo</h1>
    <p style=" color: white"><i><b>logy</b></i></p>
    <p style=" color: white">Contac +39</p>
    <hr>
    <p><i>"Th</i></p>
    <p><i>-Colin Powell</i></p>
    </div>
    </div>

    <div class="body-resume">
    <div class="about">
        <h1>About me</h1>
        <p>I .</p>
    </div>
    <div class="column1">
    <div class="education">
        <h1>Education</h1>
        <p><b><u>Elementary</u></b></p>
        <p><i><b>Sool</b></i><br>An9)</p>
        <p><i><b>Scia</b></i><br>P11)</p>

        <p><b><u>High School</u></b></p>
        <p><i><b>Hemy</b></i><br>An 2012)</p>
        <p><i><b>Frol</b></i><br>Po4)</p>
        <p><i><b>Ju</b></i><br>C 2015)</p>

        <p><b><u>College</u></b></p>
        <p><i><b>Uninan</b></i><br>C5 - 2019)</p>

    </div>
    <div class="flex-container">
      <div class="personalinfo">
          <h1>Personal Info</h1>
          <p>
      </div>
      <div class="workexper">
      </div>
    </div>


    </div>
    <div class="cert">
    </div>
    </div>

    </div>
    </main>
```

Comment: thank you however I need the personal info beside the workexper and the bottom of both is cert

Answer (score 1):

**CSS-Grid** proves out to be the powerful tool  to achieve these kinds of layouts with neat code. This such a handy tool once you apply your @media queries to work you app on small screens, since this does not follow order. We can place grid-items any where we want on our grid.

Here is  the demo.

```css
.resume-body {
  background-color: #1f2021;
}

.wrapper-body-resume {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

/* Header */
.header-resume {
  font-family: Arial;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 350px;
  z-index: 1;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgb(46, 46, 46), rgb(0, 0, 0));
}
.GP {
  background: url(../Resources/Aljon-GP.png);
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  bottom: 150px;
  left: 400px;
  position: relative;
}

.name-left {
  text-align: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 80px 0 0 0;
  margin: 0;
  left: 300px;
  position: relative;
}
.name-left h1 {
  line-height: 0;

  font-size: 30px;
  color: #ffffff;
}
.name-left p {
  color: #999999;
}
.body-resume {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

.about {
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 10px;
  font-family: Arial;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}
.about h1 {
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 5px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: Arial;
  color: #1f2021;
}
.about p {
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 5px;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-style: italic;
}

.column1 {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(8, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(5, 125px);
  gap: 0.5rem;
}
.education {
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  grid-column: 1/3;
  grid-row: 1/6;
}
.education h1 {
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 5;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: Arial;
  color: #1f2021;
}

.education p {
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 5px;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-style: italic;
}

.personalinfo {
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 10px;
  font-family: Arial;
  height: 500px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  grid-column: 3/5;
}
.personalinfo h1 {
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 5;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: Arial;
  color: #1f2021;
}
.personalinfo p {
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 5px;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-style: italic;
}
.workexper {
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 10px;
  font-family: Arial;
  height: 500px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  grid-column: 5/9;
}
.cert {
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 10px;
  font-family: Arial;
  width: 50%;
  height: 500px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  grid-column: 3/9;
  grid-row: 5/6;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <main>
      <div class="wrapper-body-resume">
        <div class="header-resume">
          <div class="GP"></div>
          <div class="name-left">
            <h1>Aljo</h1>
            <p style="color: white">
              <i><b>logy</b></i>
            </p>
            <p style="color: white">Contac +39</p>
            <hr />
            <p><i>"Th</i></p>
            <p><i>-Colin Powell</i></p>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="body-resume">
          <div class="about">
            <h1>About me</h1>
            <p>I .</p>
          </div>
          <div class="column1">
            <div class="education">
              <h1>Education</h1>
              <p>
                <b><u>Elementary</u></b>
              </p>
              <p>
                <i><b>Sool</b></i
                ><br />An9)
              </p>
              <p>
                <i><b>Scia</b></i
                ><br />P11)
              </p>

              <p>
                <b><u>High School</u></b>
              </p>
              <p>
                <i><b>Hemy</b></i
                ><br />An 2012)
              </p>
              <p>
                <i><b>Frol</b></i
                ><br />Po4)
              </p>
              <p>
                <i><b>Ju</b></i
                ><br />C 2015)
              </p>

              <p>
                <b><u>College</u></b>
              </p>
              <p>
                <i><b>Uninan</b></i
                ><br />C5 - 2019)
              </p>
            </div>
            <div class="personalinfo">
              <h1>Personal Info</h1>
              <p></p>
            </div>

            <div class="workexper"></div>
            <div class="cert"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </main>
  </body>
</html>
```

**NOTE:** The main change in the HTML file is that, I have also put the last div with `class="cert"` within my grid-container itself.

Comment: It is better to use grid than flex coloumn?

Comment: Please teach what does or how to use that grid system or is there any reference link I can rid?

Comment: Dear Friend, I am answering a query from a developer. Let me answer that and I'll get back to you to advise you :) Don't worry. Just 5-10 minutes

Comment: Thank you so much! You are a good person I appreciate it. Sure take your time.

Comment: I will share with you an awesome resource from where I initially started learning it. You can complete this is 1 or 2 hours only. Then with very small you'll have the grip on CSS-Grids.

Comment: Here is the link. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x7tLPhnA06w&list=PL4cUxeGkcC9itC4TxYMzFCfveyutyPOCY This is Shaun, Teaching on his official you tube channel NetNinja. This guy is a wonderful person. He has made learning very easy.

Comment: Best way to say thanks is by Accepting the Answer here on SO. This helps both the questioner and the answerer. Feel free to Accept whatever answer you feel helped your purpose. And where you learned some stuff. :) If after watching the CSS-Grid Tutorial you still need more help. Just drop me an email @ emmeiwhite@gmail.com . Happy coding

Answer (score 0):

```css
.resume-body {
  background-color: #1f2021;
}

.wrapper-body-resume {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

/* Header */
.header-resume {
  font-family: Arial;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 350px;
  z-index: 1;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgb(46, 46, 46), rgb(0, 0, 0));
}
.GP {
  background: url(../Resources/Aljon-GP.png);
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  bottom: 150px;
  left: 400px;
  position: relative;
}

.name-left {
  text-align: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 80px 0 0 0;
  margin: 0;
  left: 300px;
  position: relative;
}
.name-left h1 {
  line-height: 0;

  font-size: 30px;
  color: #ffffff;
}
.name-left p {
  color: #999999;
}
.body-resume {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

.about {
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 10px;
  font-family: Arial;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}
.about h1 {
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 5px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: Arial;
  color: #1f2021;
}
.about p {
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 5px;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-style: italic;
}

.personalinfo {
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 10px;
  font-family: Arial;
  width: 22%;
  height: 500px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}
.personalinfo h1 {
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 5;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: Arial;
  color: #1f2021;
}
.personalinfo p {
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 5px;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-style: italic;
}
.column1 {
  display: flex;
  flex: row;
}
.education {
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 10px;
  width: 30%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.education h1 {
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 5;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: Arial;
  color: #1f2021;
}

.education p {
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 5px;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-style: italic;
}
.workexper {
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 10px;
  font-family: Arial;
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}
.cert {
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 10px;
  font-family: Arial;
  width: 50%;
  height: 500px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}
```

```html
<main> 
<div class="wrapper-body-resume">

<div class="header-resume">
<div class="GP"></div>
<div class="name-left">
<h1>Aljo</h1>
<p style=" color: white"><i><b>logy</b></i></p>
<p style=" color: white">Contac +39</p>
<hr>
<p><i>"Th</i></p>
<p><i>-Colin Powell</i></p>
</div>
</div>

<div class="body-resume">
<div class="about">
    <h1>About me</h1>
    <p>I .</p>
</div>
<div class="column1">
<div class="education">
    <h1>Education</h1>
    <p><b><u>Elementary</u></b></p>
    <p><i><b>Sool</b></i><br>An9)</p>
    <p><i><b>Scia</b></i><br>P11)</p>

    <p><b><u>High School</u></b></p>
    <p><i><b>Hemy</b></i><br>An 2012)</p>
    <p><i><b>Frol</b></i><br>Po4)</p>
    <p><i><b>Ju</b></i><br>C 2015)</p>

    <p><b><u>College</u></b></p>
    <p><i><b>Uninan</b></i><br>C5 - 2019)</p>

</div>
<div class="personalinfo">
    <h1>Personal Info</h1>
    <p>
</div>
<div class="workexper">
</div>

<div class="cert"> <!--I have moved this into your column div!-->
</div>

</div>
</div>

</div>
</main>
```

You just needed to move your 'cert' div into the 'column' div because you had display flex on the column

Comment: Thank you, what I mean is under the 2 rectangle not behind them.